# What am i missing? sklearn fit module

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I think input to Machine Learning cannot be text in .fit what should I use then or how should i change my code? This ai should be training with Year month and days and it should give as output Crops (First, Second, Third) (I don't know what more details to add but i need to post more details so im just typing random stuff at the moment.
code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

event_data = pd.read_excel("Jacob's Farming Contest.xlsx")
event_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)
X = event_data.drop(columns=['First Crop', 'Second Crop', 'Third Crop'])
y = event_data.drop(columns=['Year', 'Month', 'Day'])
X_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
# predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-3fbcae548642> in <module>
     11 
     12 model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
---> 13 model.fit(X_train, y_train)
     14 # predictions = model.predict(X_test)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    888         """
    889 
--> 890         super().fit(
    891             X, y,
    892             sample_weight=sample_weight,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, check_input, X_idx_sorted)
    179 
    180         if is_classification:
--> 181             check_classification_targets(y)
    182             y = np.copy(y)
    183 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
    167     y : array-like
    168     """
--> 169     y_type = type_of_target(y)
    170     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
    171                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
    248         raise ValueError("y cannot be class 'SparseSeries' or 'SparseArray'")
    249 
--> 250     if is_multilabel(y):
    251         return 'multilabel-indicator'
    252 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in is_multilabel(y)
    150                  _is_integral_float(np.unique(y.data))))
    151     else:
--> 152         labels = np.unique(y)
    153 
    154         return len(labels) < 3 and (y.dtype.kind in 'biu' or  # bool, int, uint

<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
    261     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
    262     if axis is None:
--> 263         ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    264         return _unpack_tuple(ret)
    265 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
    309         aux = ar[perm]
    310     else:
--> 311         ar.sort()
    312         aux = ar
    313     mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

This is Jacob's Farming Contest.xlsx:

```
    Year    Month   Day First Crop  Second Crop Third Crop
0   101 1   1   0   0   0
1   101 1   2   Cactus  Carrot  Cocoa Beans
2   101 1   3   0   0   0
3   101 1   4   0   0   0
4   101 1   5   Mushroom    Sugar CaNether Wart Wheat
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
367 101 12  27  Cactus  Carrot  Mushroom
368 101 12  28  0   0   0
369 101 12  29  0   0   0
370 101 12  30  Cocoa Beans Pumpkin Sugar CaNether Wart
371 101 12  31  0   0   0
```

Comment: You need to encoded your 'features' you can't have strings such that they are represented by numbers.   Look at One Hot Encoding as an example.

Comment: @ScottBoston I use numebrs and not like pumpkins etc. Still not working

Comment: Try `event_data.fillna("NA", inplace=True)` instead of `event_data.fillna(0, inplace=True)` or `event_data.drop_na()` to remove these useless rows